# Undefined error when loading slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, flexslider

I am loading two sliders on a page - and as of now my main slider is working. I have a secondary slider that was working until recently - now I see this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function) 
f.event.handle 
i.handle.k
```

I know it's hard with out all of the script files here - but here is the call for my second slider that is giving the error. Any thoughts?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  $(window).load(function() {
     $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you maybe upgrade the jquery version ?

Comment: I did - and it was a conflict between my two slider types - so what I did was use 
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>

Answer (score 0):

Updated jQuery - and then found conflicts so found this to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
 <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
     jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide"
      });
   });
</script>
```